# PHP 'if' statement spanning multiple lines?

Tags: php, syntax

I've been trying to get this to work but I keep getting parsing errors:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ( isset($_POST['agree']) == false  || 
         isset($_POST['name'] == false    || 
         isset($_POST['email'] == false   ||  
         isset($_POST['title'] == false   ||  
         isset($_POST['program'] == false || 
         isset($_POST['course'] == false  ||  
         isset($_POST['file'] == false    ||) {
        echo ' <font color="red"> Please complete all required fields </font><br><br> ';
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this in PHP? It's to make my code more readable.

Comment: To save you writing loads of code, you can replace each `isset() == false` with `!isset($_POST['agree'])`, for example.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible, but you have a last trailing `||` with no following expression and you're missing a bunch of closing `)`, which is giving you the parse error.

Also, you can abbreviate that to

```
if (!isset($_POST['agree'], $_POST['name'], ...))
```

or

```
if (array_diff(array('agree', 'name', ...), array_keys($_POST)))
```

Please note though that all this is probably not testing what you want to test. If you have a form, all those fields will be *set*. Unless the user actively manipulates the form, all fields will be submitted with the value `""` (an empty string), which makes `isset` return `true`. You're either looking for `empty` or for more customized tests.

Answer (score 15):

Umm, if you correct the parentheses and leave out the last `||`, this *is* valid php code:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   if (!isset($_POST['agree']) || 
       !isset($_POST['name']) || 
       !isset($_POST['email']) ||  
       !isset($_POST['title']) ||  
       !isset($_POST['program']) || 
       !isset($_POST['course'])  ||  
       !isset($_POST['file'])
   ) {
       echo '<font color="red">Please complete all required fields</font><br>';
   }
}
```

By the way, the `<font>` element has been [deprecated](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#font), use CSS instead.

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't it be simpler to do it like this?

```
foreach(array('submit','agree','name','email','title','program','course','file') as $value) {
    if(!isset($_POST[$value])) {
        /* insert form incomplete routine here */
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Your are missing the closing parentheses for almost all of your `isset`s. You also have an extra '||' at the end.

Note: the error message says this very clearly:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_IS_EQUAL, expecting ',' or ')' in ... on line 5
```